# how to get the file path of downloaded pdf files in iphone/iphone simulator

Tags: iphone

I want to get the file path of the downloaded files from website in iphone/iphone simulator..At present when try to view any pdf of any websites in iphone simulator the pdf can be viewed but i want to know where it is getting downloaded(download path)in the iphone simulator.Can you help me out

Answer (score 1):

It might be saved in Document Directory, because it's the only place where we can save our files which are created or downloaded at runtime. And if you are not saving your downloading file then it's in temporary directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a document directory or an iPhone simulator on an iPhone. The answer to that specific question does not exist on this site or any other

Answer (score 0):

navigate to the iphone simulator folder in your mac machine and in the folder navigate to the users/media/downloads.if i am correct you may find it in that folder.